# Machine Learning integration with FLASK

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, artificial-intelligence, pickle

I have a model trained and saved in a folder. I want to load it to integrate its result within a Flask web application.
However, I have the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\Downloads\Cours\Hackathon\hackhathon2\app.py", line 30, in result
    guess = apply_model(prompt, options)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\Downloads\Cours\Hackathon\hackhathon2\utils.py", line 68, in apply_model
    loaded_trainer = pickle.load(open('trainer_state.pkl','rb'))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MultipleChoiceCollator' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\Users\\arthu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Scripts\\flask.exe\\__main__.py'>
```

when I use pickle to get the model

I have the code below to train and save the model. I provide it just in case but it works, in a not-FLASK application I can give an input and it will predict an answer as an output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datasets import Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMultipleChoice, TrainingArguments, Trainer
from dataclasses import dataclass
from transformers.tokenization_utils_base import PreTrainedTokenizerBase, PaddingStrategy
from typing import Optional, Union
import torch
from utils import MultipleChoiceCollator

# Chargement des données
data = pd.read_csv('train_anat.csv')

# Séparation des données en ensembles d'entraînement et de test (4:1 ratio)
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Création des ensembles de données
train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(train_data)
test_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(test_data)

# Initialisation du tokenizer
checkpoint = 'roberta-base'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

# Mapping des options aux indices
option_indices = {opt: idx for idx, opt in enumerate('ABCDE')}
index_options = {idx: opt for idx, opt in enumerate('ABCDE')}

# Prétraitement des données
def prepare_data(ex):
    context = [ex['prompt']] * 5
    choices = [ex[option] for option in 'ABCDE']
    tokenized_input = tokenizer(context, choices, truncation=True)
    tokenized_input['labels'] = option_indices[ex['answer']]
    return tokenized_input

processed_dataset = train_dataset.map(prepare_data, batched=False)

processed_eval_dataset = test_dataset.map(prepare_data, batched=False)

# Configuration du modèle et de l'entraîneur
model = AutoModelForMultipleChoice.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

from datasets import load_metric
accuracy_metric = load_metric("accuracy")
f1_metric = load_metric("f1")

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return {
        "accuracy": accuracy_metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels),
        "f1": f1_metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels, average="macro")
    }


train_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='bert_finetuned',
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    num_train_epochs=4,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    report_to='none'
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=train_args,
    train_dataset=processed_dataset,
    eval_dataset=processed_eval_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=MultipleChoiceCollator(tokenizer),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

# Entraînement du modèle
trainer.train()

trainer.evaluate()

trainer.save_model("./train_anat")

# Prédictions
predictions = trainer.predict(processed_dataset)

import pickle

# Sauvegarde du Trainer après l'entraînement et l'évaluation
with open("trainer_state.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(trainer, f)
```

I created a utils.py handling the model loading and prediction :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datasets import Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMultipleChoice, TrainingArguments, Trainer
from dataclasses import dataclass
from transformers.tokenization_utils_base import PreTrainedTokenizerBase, PaddingStrategy
from typing import Optional, Union
import torch
from utils import MultipleChoiceCollator

# Chargement des données
data = pd.read_csv('train_anat.csv')

# Séparation des données en ensembles d'entraînement et de test (4:1 ratio)
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Création des ensembles de données
train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(train_data)
test_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(test_data)

# Initialisation du tokenizer
checkpoint = 'roberta-base'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

# Mapping des options aux indices
option_indices = {opt: idx for idx, opt in enumerate('ABCDE')}
index_options = {idx: opt for idx, opt in enumerate('ABCDE')}

# Prétraitement des données
def prepare_data(ex):
    context = [ex['prompt']] * 5
    choices = [ex[option] for option in 'ABCDE']
    tokenized_input = tokenizer(context, choices, truncation=True)
    tokenized_input['labels'] = option_indices[ex['answer']]
    return tokenized_input

processed_dataset = train_dataset.map(prepare_data, batched=False)

processed_eval_dataset = test_dataset.map(prepare_data, batched=False)

# Configuration du modèle et de l'entraîneur
model = AutoModelForMultipleChoice.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

from datasets import load_metric
accuracy_metric = load_metric("accuracy")
f1_metric = load_metric("f1")

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return {
        "accuracy": accuracy_metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels),
        "f1": f1_metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels, average="macro")
    }


train_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='bert_finetuned',
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    num_train_epochs=4,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    report_to='none'
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=train_args,
    train_dataset=processed_dataset,
    eval_dataset=processed_eval_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=MultipleChoiceCollator(tokenizer),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

# Entraînement du modèle
trainer.train()

trainer.evaluate()

trainer.save_model("./train_anat")

# Prédictions
predictions = trainer.predict(processed_dataset)

import pickle

# Sauvegarde du Trainer après l'entraînement et l'évaluation
with open("trainer_state.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(trainer, f)
```

Unfortunately, I have the error above when I use it within a FLASK application like this :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from utils import apply_model

app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route('/')
def quiz_demo():
    return render_template('quiz.html')

@app.route('/answer', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Get form answers
        prompt = request.form['question']
        options = [
            request.form['answer1'],
            request.form['answer2'],
            request.form['answer3'],
            request.form['answer4'],
            request.form['answer5']
        ]

        # Error handler

        if prompt.strip() == '' or any(answer.strip() == '' for answer in options):
            return 'You should first fill the forms for question & answers.'

        guess = apply_model(prompt, options)

        return render_template('answer.html', question=prompt, answers=options, result=guess)

    return redirect(url_for('quiz_demo'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```